# Using components in admin-generator modules, it's possible? how?

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, admin-generator

I need to build a admin interface like this [image](http://www.dropmocks.com/mBuNQJ) show. In the past I use components for that purpose but now because the modules are generated trough `admin-generator` I don't know how to get this done. I check all this docs [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5857037/how-to-use-a-component-with-admin-generator), [2](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/book/1_2/es/14-Generators), [3](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/reference/1_4/en/06-Admin-Generator) but without any clue on how to do this. I also created a `components.class.php` under `modules/sdriving_empresa/actions` folder and include the component in the view `include_component('sdriving_empresa')` but get this error:

> sfComponents initialization failed.

Any help?

Comment: include_component('sdriving_empresa', 'actionName') maybe?

Comment: which component is that?

Comment: well the one you want ! see Ixark answer, that's the same than mine basically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Tabs and Partials, the easy way :)**

One of the best possible javascripts for that purpose is [Javascript Tabifier](http://www.barelyfitz.com/projects/tabber). Its easy 
to install and play with it. You will find a lot of other Javascript and jQuery Tabbers, get the one you most like.

I would advise you to learn everything about [symfony 1 partials](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/07-Inside-the-View-Layer#chapter_07_sub_partials) in order to get the job easily done. Usually partials are a piece of code which is saved in an external file, and does is loaded later in any part of your code. Its like a variable with a lot of html and php code. Partials (the external files) allow also to receive input variables, so its easy to send them ids from related modules or tables.

Lets look at an example with Tabifier with two Tabs, information and Admin and two partials

***editSuccess.php***

```
$sModuleName = sfContext::getInstance()->getModuleName();
$sbasepathtabs = $sModuleName . '/tabs';
<div class='tabber' id='tabberglobal1'>
    <div class='tabbertab' title='Information' >
        <?php
            include_partial($sbasepathtabs . '/_information/_information', array('form' => $form));
        ?>
    </div>

  <div class="tabbertab" title="Admin" >
    <?php
        include_partial($sbasepathtabs . '/_admin/_admin', array('form' => $form));
    ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Easily setup it:**

1. Inside your module template folder, create the folder: **`/_tabs`**
2. Inside the folder /_tabs create the folder **`/_information`** and **`/_admin`**
3. Inside the folder /_tabs/_information create the file partial: **`_information.php`**
4. Inside the folder /_tabs/_admin create the file partial: **`_admin.php`**

Inside each one of those files partials write anything you want. 
Those partials will receive the left variable form: array('form' => $form). 
You can send to the partials more than one variable: array('form' => $form, 'variable2' => $formnumber2)

When you write a partial, in example the partial _information, you can easily get the form object and its values in the template with:

```
$id = $form->getObject()->getId();
```

For normal variables you wont need to call getObject.

Finally, take a deep look at the documentation of both things, symfony partials and Javascript Tabifier. They will solve you anything you need.

**Backend Admin Generator:**

Admin generator automatically generates all templates in the cache folder. Example:

```
cache\backend\prod\modules\autoTbPrueba1Backend\templates
cache\backend\prod\modules\autoTbPrueba1Backend\templates\indexSuccess.php
```

Most of its files are already partials, pay attention to the files who has the _ symbol in their name, they are partials. This means that most of the work is already done for you, and the only thing you will have to do is to override some of the partials (TbPrueba1Backend/list_header which is the file _list_header.php) or even the full template (indexSuccess.php) with the extended information you need.
In order to override backend generated templates and partials, you can copy those files to the template folder of your module:

```
apps\backend\modules\TbPrueba1Backend\templates
apps\backend\modules\TbPrueba1Backend\templates\indexSuccess.php
```

Set there any additional information you need, and if you dont see anything new while refreshing the web, remember to clear the symfony cache (symfony cc).

Once you have override the the templates and partials with the new information, the only thing you need now is to write/add those partials inside the div tabs created by your bootstrap framework as I described above.

For a good explanation of the admin generator:
[Symfony 1.4 change admin generator actions or templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687058/symfony-1-4-change-admin-generator-actions-or-templates)
http://www.slideshare.net/loalf/symfony-y-admin-generator
http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/jobeet/1_4/en/12?orm=Doctrine

Comment: nice explanation but useless to me, why? because I'm working mostly with `doctrine:generate-admin` task modules. I mean I'm using this task to generate modules, in that case how partials will fit there? I'm using Twitter Bootstrap as CSS framework so I'm using their tabs and this is not a problem because I know them well

Comment: Added information about the admin generator, how it works, how to overwrite templates and adding them to the div tabs of bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

You need the moduleName and the componentName in your include_component()

```
function include_component($moduleName, $componentName, $vars = array())
{
  echo get_component($moduleName, $componentName, $vars);
}
```

Or maybe your module is in the wrong application. In that case, you may consider moving it in a plugin